# Asterisk dial function answered extension

Tags: asterisk

When I dial multiple extension with dial function, I couldn't find which extension answered.

I'm using dial function with these parameters dial(SIP/1001&SIP/1002&SIP/1003,30,tTr) and I'm checking results on the real-time table with MySQL. But when I check the cdr record on table its looking like

+---------------------+-----------------------------+--------------+------------+----------------+---------------------------+---------------------------+------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------+---------+-------------+----------+-------------+-----------+----------------+----------------+----------+-------------+
| calldate            | clid                        | src          | dst        | dcontext       | channel                   | dstchannel                | lastapp    | lastdata                                                                        | duration | billsec | disposition | amaflags | accountcode | userfield | uniqueid       | linkedid       | sequence | peeraccount |
+---------------------+-----------------------------+--------------+------------+----------------+---------------------------+---------------------------+------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------+---------+-------------+----------+-------------+-----------+----------------+----------------+----------+-------------+
| 2018-04-06 17:10:17 | "05555555555" <05555555555> | 05555555555| aa     | aaContext | SIP/908500000000-000000f7 | SIP/908500000000-000000f8 | Dial       | SIP/1001&SIP/1002&SIP/1003 |      462 |     435 | ANSWERED    |        3 |             |           | 1523049017.247 | 1523049017.247 | 269      |             |

So, I can see which channel answered, but there is no extension on it

Answer (score 0):

You can have 3 solutions

1) CEL. Channel Level Log in newer asterisk version allow you get much more events per call.

2) Dial like Local/1001@ext&Local/1002@ext&Local/1003@ext.
This way you will have more cdrs in ext context.

3) Use on-answer macro and record which ext answered.